# Cuda 9 RC + VS2017 + CMake not working

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to get a CUDA project to compile using CMake and Visual Studio 2017,
but the build fails, details below.

**System:**
Windows 10 Pro x64
Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.3.2
CUDA 9 RC (Version 9.0.103)
CMake 3.9.1 (Generator: Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64)

**The dummy project:**

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(vs17cuda)

# Cuda is always required
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -std=c++11" )

add_subdirectory(src)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt

```
cuda_add_executable(vs17cuda main.cu)
set_target_properties(vs17cuda PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
target_link_libraries(vs17cuda ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
```

src/main.cu

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__global__ void DummyKernel()
{
    //do nothing
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    DummyKernel<<<4, 4>>>();
}
```

**Console output: (german messages translated to english)**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: vs17cuda, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Building NVCC (Device) object src/CMakeFiles/vs17cuda.dir/Debug/vs17cuda_generated_main.cu.obj
1>Failed to run C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/VC/bin/cl.exe (File not found).
1>
1>).
1>CMake Error at vs17cuda_generated_main.cu.obj.Debug.cmake:222 (message):
1>  Error generating
1>  C:/Users/Sebastian/Documents/C++/vs17cuda/build/src/CMakeFiles/vs17cuda.dir//Debug/vs17cuda_generated_main.cu.obj
1>
1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
1>Done building project "vs17cuda.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

How can the build be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems CUDA is now fully integrated with CMake. Functions from the FindCUDA package, such as `cuda_add_executable` now revert to the default `add_executable`. The details are spelled out in a recent blog post from NVIDIA: [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/building-cuda-applications-cmake/). I cloned the Github repo linked to in that post, and it did work for me; though only for a 64-bit build.

Comment: This works for me.
I also found another solution: just let MVCC generate the project, this is done everytime the MVCC compiler detects a change in the CMakeLists. I don't use e.g. the CMake GUI for the generation, except for the initial one.